# Oil-eating animal; possible?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, evolution

I saw a movie where oil companies stumbled upon these fictional underground aquatic deep-sea animals that survived on eating and digesting the oil where they lived. They had squid/octopus-like bodies and were as smart (possibly smarter) than dolphins or apes (not us, though).

These are the conditions:

- very high pressure since they lived in deep underground caves filled with high-pressure water
- very intelligent
- social
- oil (petroleum) eating

**Is it possible for an animal to survive and develop the ability to eat oil in these conditions?**

Comment: Theoretically yes, this is possible, but in practice that would be quite a different evolutionary path that should require a whole ecosystem.

Comment: "Oil" mean "petroleum", right? In this case, [*Alcanivorax borkumensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcanivorax) shows that obtaining "energy primarily from consuming [alkanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkane)" (Wikipedia) is indeed possible. And cephalopods and indeed highly intelligent (for invertebrates).

Comment: What movie was it?

Comment: It's called Monster Trucks since farther in a teenager builds his car so that the animal can drive it. i found it on Amazon Prime.

Comment: I'm with @AlexP.  Please edit your question and specify what oil we're talking about.  Humans eat oil (vegetable, mammalian, etc.) all the time.  When dealing the imaginative and creative questions and answers, it's very important to be as specific as you can.  Assumptions can get your question closed as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Do you specifically require them to consume the oil for nutrition; or are you open enough to e.g. consuming things that are found in the oil (and being able to deal with swallowing large amounts of oil though not directly getting nutrition from the oil itself).

Comment: Would these creature's flatulence contribute to global warming?

Comment: did some oil research and found that, yes, petroleum would be the kind they would most likely eat.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The biology of such a creature is plausible - oil is an energy-rich substance and there are bacteria that can digest it.  These creatures may have a symbiotic relationship with such bacteria.  The real question is why they would be intelligent.

Most intelligent animals eat a wide variety of food sources (they need to learn which are good for eating and which are not, and remember the tricks for eating each kind of food) and many are carnivorous to some degree (they need to outsmart prey).  Grazers are rarely very intelligent, and sucking on oil wells seems to be pretty similar to grazing.  However, there is one intelligent species that may have evolved with an ecology similar to your oil-eaters: Elephants.

It is theorized that elephants evolved their substantial brains not so much for the sake of finding food, but for finding water.  When resources are rare, far apart, clumped together, and tend to vary in how accessible they are (pools appearing and disappearing seasonally), it is important to be able to remember where those resources are in order to migrate between them.  It is also important to remember what conditions are associated with the appearance or disappearance of a given pool (heat and rain).  A social hierarchy may develop as herds migrate together, and older individuals may remember pools that younger ones do not.

An analogy can be made between elephants searching for water and these sea-creatures searching for oil.  Oil wells are rare and far apart, and many are fed from deeper sources or shale that slowly replenish the easily-accessible reservoirs over time, at least until the deeper wells are depleted (presumably the biological mechanisms of these creatures are not quite as effective as the best human equipment, so they are only able to access the most easily-accessible wells).  Finding new oil wells is difficult (perhaps the creatures have some kind of natural sonar ability) so being able to remember to return to the old wells decades later will be a major survival advantage, as will judging how quickly each well tends to refill.  As with elephants, this will likely result in a complex social hierarchy with elderly leaders that remember the old wells, migrating in huge herds across the ocean floor.

Answer (score 39):

**It is totally plausible.  You would need commensal microbes to do the metabolic work.**

Consider cellulose - loaded with energy but difficult for metazoans to digest.  Those that can digest it (e.g. termites, ruminants) have commensal bacteria in their guts which have the metabolic machinery to handle cellulose.  The metazoans house these organisms and keep them safe; in exchange the microbes release the nutrition in the cellulose and nourish their hosts.

This same model could work with petrochemicals.  There are microbes which can digest these energy rich compounds.  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3815313/
and one would expect that just as termites house cellulose-digesting microbes, metazoans in environments rich in petrochemicals would house petrochemical digesting organisms.

Comment: But the termite metazoans need protection from predators. Why would oil-eating metazoans need protection? Or rather, what would they need protection from...

Comment: Perhaps the microorganism itself evolved into a multicellular life form? Convergent evolution could easily whip up a cephalopodesque body.

Comment: One can make a strong case that multicellular bodies - all of us -  are masterful tricks by prokaryotic life.   They evolved a biological stronghold to house them.  Our bodies included.

Comment: @Willk: The concept that we’re just walking talking fortresses amuses me greatly.

Comment: @JohnLocke They would need protection from predators evolved to eat them.

Comment: @MartinBonner What would evolve to live in an oil well and eat microbes or metazoans?

Comment: @JoeBloggs That;s exactly what we are. The number of *human* cells in your body is outnumbered at least 3-to-1 by the number of *non-human* cells that are just tagging along for the ride - though some of them are "good to have around" from the human's perspective for example some of them synthesize vitamins, which is nice of them!

Comment: @JohnLocke needing protection isn't really that relevant. Microbes are generally [_r_ strategists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R/K_selection_theory#r-selection), their success is mainly a function of how quickly they get to new resources. And a multicellular host is a great way of getting around. For oil-eating microbes it would be particularly useful, seeing as they can't rely on ocean currents to carry them to their food source because the food is not hydrophilic.

Comment: @leftaroundabout My understanding was that they lived inside of the wells, where mobility would not really help, and travel to different wells was not the norm.

Comment: Protection isn't needed. Easier access to food sources works too.

Comment: @JoeBloggs as my biology teacher once asked the class, is DNA a tool we use to replicate ourselves, or are our bodies and minds a tool DNA uses?

Comment: @mbrig: We’re just a really good battleship AI if you think about it.

Comment: I question the likelihood of such an organism sustainably existing, though. Cellulose, though complex, is a substance that is created as part of another life form's natural life span, so it can be depended upon as a renewable source of food. Oil, however, is a finite resource that takes millions of years to form, so when it becomes scarce, it isn't going to be replenished again until long after any macro-organisms that have evolved to eat it will have gone extinct. So while its theoretically for such an animal to exist, I can't really think that it would for very long.

Comment: @Abion47 - there are organisms that subsist on methane that seeps up to the habitable zones from points deeper.   https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/phenomena/2011/01/06/bacteria-ate-up-all-the-methane-that-spilled-from-the-deepwater-horizon-well/. This would be the strategy of the oil eaters as well - live at a place where nourishment comes from the ground.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but those organisms are all mostly single-celled organisms, nothing bigger than plankton at the biggest and most complex, where OP sounded like he was thinking larger, maybe even much larger. Bacteria and simple plankton-like animals, sure, but I just can't imagine a scenario where *macro*organisms that lived off of oil would be a sustainable ecosystem.

Answer (score 7):

Others have covered that biologically this is quite plausible, but the main issue I see is most petrochemicals have a very short life near oxygen, and have no scope for squeezing a little bit more out by some form of anaerobic process.

The problem with large life is that they need oxygen, but oil requires an anoxic environment to be created and persist.

The oil eating organisms are all bacteria because of the lack of oxygen.

Your creature is either going to need to process the most difficult oils (tar) or spend its time traveling between the surface and depths of the sea.

So in summary you have either beasts roaming the land searching and digging for tar or perhaps some deep diving cephalopod consuming methyl hydrates formed on the edges of continental shelves, or drinking from natural seepage above reserves.

Answer (score 2):

It is not only possible, oil eating animals *already* [exist](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+oil+eating+bacteria+work&oq=does+oil+eating+bac&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.17689j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  On top of that, oil is extremely close to fat chemically, as they are chains of hydrocarbons.  Essentially, every animal on the planet eats some form of fat from other animals, even from some plants. Oil and petroleum are full of energy.  Its no stretch for an animal to evolve to take advantage of that as a good source.